# Why Shell script randomly stops fetching password from Keychain?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, security, keychain

I am fetching the password from keychain using below command

```
login_name=`security find-generic-password -l 'Main_screen' -a first_screen_user -w`
```

It fetches results without any problem. 
But sometimes I have seen if I do not restart my laptop for 2-3 weeks. It suddenly stop returning the value.
Is there any particular reason for that and how to make it work for that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you see when it 'stops returning the value'? Try running with `-v` to get more info.

One thing that took me a while to discover is that keychains can lock after a timeout or 'sleep':

Run `Keychain Access`, right click on the keychain you use, and select `Change Settings for Keychain ...`. See if any of the `Lock after X minutes of inactivity` or `Lock when sleeping` checkboxes are selected.

If one or two are selected, you can either uncheck them, or make sure to run `security unlock-keychain` and repeating your command if you get no value.

Comment: Thansk for replying 
I will surely check with -v option , next time it happens.
When it is not working , the value of the variable is blank
The Keychain keep on getting locked after 5 min as I have set that time.
But it ask me password if it is locked .